# What's the best way do determine if an HWND represents a top-level window?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

Is it to check for the WS_CHILD bit:

```
    LONG style = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);
    int isTopLevel = !(style & WS_CHILD);
```

Or is there a better way?

**Assume**: Straight C calling only existing Windows API code.

Comment: Checking for the absence of the `WS_CHILD` style is the way to do it - any window that isn't a child is a top-level window.

Comment: @Jonathan - however, there are top-level with WS_CHILD (child of DesktopWindow)

Comment: All windows are children of the desktop in the window hierarchy, but only those with `WS_CHILD` set are actually child windows.

Comment: Once again, if you do not understand: there are top-level with WS_CHILD.

Comment: Conversely, the window can be not WS_CHILD but thus be not top-level

Comment: Thanks for your comments, kero. That's why I asked the question -- it seems this rather simple seeming problem is quite tricky in practise!

Comment: Please provide an example of a "top-level with WS_CHILD" window, as that makes no sense to me.

Comment: Please: for example, take any standard ComboBox (with CBS_DROPDOWNLIST or CBS_DROPDOWN) and test its dropdown list (ComboLBox).

Comment: I'm unsure what I'm meant to look at - its dropdown list has WS_CHILD set, so it's a child window. What in your mind makes it a top-level window?

Comment: Please concentrate and read MSDN's Remark to "EnumWindows": "The EnumWindows function does not enumerate child windows, with the exception of a few top-level windows owned by the system that have the WS_CHILD style".

Comment: @kero: that sounds like an edge case to me.  Depending on what the programmer actually wants to know for, those edge cases might need to be treated as parent windows, as child windows, or it might not matter.

Comment: Why did you tag this `C++` if the question states "Assume: Straight C"?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- Way #1: Test `hWnd==GetAncestor(hWnd,GA_ROOT)`
- Way #2: Use `IsTopLevelWindow` (user32 Win7, undocumented)

Answer (score 1):

The [GetParent() API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns the parent or owner of the current window.

Comment: The first line of the doc I linked to says "Retrieves a handle to the specified window's parent or owner." And talks about retrieving the owner window later in the article.

Comment: @chris: The docs say: "If the window is a child window, the return value is a handle to the parent window. If the window is a top-level window with the WS_POPUP style, the return value is a handle to the owner window."

Comment: @jwismar, I'm blind today. I read everything about `GetWindow` and `GetAncestor` and somehow missed the first remarks paragraph.

Comment: @jwismar, GetParent is completely useless.

Comment: @kero Can you explain why?

Comment: @jwismar, here is my old demo just on this topic: http://files.rsdn.ru/42164/parentowner.zip

Answer (score 0):

Your method is possible (But I think you had better to check if it is a overlapped/popup window too). There is maybe another way -- That is to enum all top level windows and to check if your windows is included in result.