# Win32 api - how to check if a specified handle is a window? (and isn't a control inside a window)

Tags: c#, winapi, window, controls, handle

My aim is to get the handle of a window I click. I'm using a global mouse hook and then `GetCursorPos` and `WindowFromPoint`). When I click on a button (or other controls) I get the button's handle. Using `GetParent` I can find the parent window, so I need to check if the handle I have is a window or not.

I have tried `GetClassName` but it's not what I'm looking for.

Any ideas appreciated (also using other approaches).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE) & WS_CHILD) {
    // window is a child window
} else {
    // window is a top-level window
}
```

Comment: SetParent helps build a window without WS_CHILD but not top-level. (As logical complement to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16973995/whats-the-best-way-do-determine-if-an-hwnd-represents-a-top-level-window/16975012#16975012)...

Comment: Still harping on about the mysterious child-but-not-child windows I see? :)

Comment: Cool solution ;) However to get the handle of the parent window I have also discovered this: `while(GetParent(Hwnd)!=0){ Hwnd = GetParent(Hwnd); }`

Comment: @Jonathan, I hope you liked this :-)

Comment: @Scanzy, GetParent = hwndParent or hwndOwner or 0 (i.e. it may be top-level owned window without children).

Comment: @kero what do you mean?

Comment: @kero got it ;) you're right but (I haven't said it) in case of popup window I wanted to get the owner's handle :p

Comment: how could this work if GetWindowLong returns an IntPtr not a boolean? neither does WS_CHILD